# Ski treadmill materials

Tags: classical-mechanics, friction

This [ski treadmill](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sIQe9E10fME) is not much of an incline, but it still allows people to ski and carve out turns. What materials have such a low coefficient of friction, yet allow higher friction at higher pressures (the "carving" part of carving). Is the treadmill coated in water that gets displaced at higher pressure?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endless_slope